# UITableViewController width is incorrect when app launches in landscape orientation

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7, uikit

I'm working on a iPad with iOS7.

I have custom `UITableViewController` subclass that is working very well (i.e. it's displaying all the data as expected), except that it doesn't properly set the width when the device starts in landscape orientation.

If the app is started in portrait mode, the width of the table view is correct - it takes up the entire width of the screen. When I rotate to landscape view, it resizes the table view content to take up all available space. This is fine.

However, if I start the app in landscape view, the width of the table view is only about 3/4 of the available space. This incorrect width persists if I then rotate to portrait mode; the content is resized, but it still only takes up 3/4 of the available width/

I'm not using custom `UITableViewCell`s, just `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle`.

I've tried adding an `autoresizingMask` to both the cells and the UITableView. However, I'm not convinced I'm doing it in the right place. I've been setting the autoresizingMask in the `init` method of my TableViewController subclass:

`self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth`.

What do I need to do to get my table view to automatically fit the available width when starting in landscape mode?

Comment: Which CGRect are you passing to your UITableView upon creation?

Comment: Have you ever found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you do **not** create a `UIView` from a NIB, then you should either be passing physical dimensions to its `initWithFrame`, or set it using the `frame` property.

```
[[aSubView alloc] initWithFrame:someFrame];
```

As you pointed out, it is not the `autoresizingMask` that is incorrect, since the view does already resize, only improperly ; it's the view frame that is incorrect.

As an example, you may want to pass the bounds of the enclosing view, which will anchor your subview at (0,0) filling the superview in all directions.

```
[[aSubView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
```

Comment: I'm not actually manually allocating the view, since I'm using a subclass of `UITableViewController`, which I assume creates the view. Is there a method I need to override to manually allocate the view so that I can pass it a frame?

Comment: Let me assume then that you are doing something like `MyVC *tableVC = [[MyVC alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];` followed by `[self.navigationController pushViewController:tableVC animated:YES];`. Or maybe you do it from a NIB? `MyVC *tableVC = [[MyVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"my_vc" bundle:nil];`. If so, do not touch `autoresizingMask`. A UITableViewController pushed as the top VC will work out of the box. Are you properly implementing `-shouldAutorotate` and `-supportedInterfaceOrientations`?